# Chef server, install a cookbook that is not from cookbook site

Tags: chef-infra

We have a testing environment that consists of one server, one client and another client as workstation.

I am aware of the command

```
# knife cookbook site install apache2
```

but this command generates an error because I cannot even download using the cookbook site.
When I download,

```
# knife cookbook site download apache2
```

this comes out,

```
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to cookbooks.opscode.com:80 for /api/v1/cookbooks/apache2, retry 1/5
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to cookbooks.opscode.com:80 for /api/v1/cookbooks/apache2, giving up
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

If you have something to solve this issue, please also share but my main issue is to know a way to install a cookbook manually? Not from the cookbook site?
I tried downloading it from the site using the 'Download' button there and then copying the tar.gz to the workstation, uploading it to the chef server, adding the cookbook to the node's runlist recipe and then executing

```
# chef-client
```

in the workstation. Is this the same way as installing it? If not, is there a way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have at your chef repo the .chef folder and does it have your credentials (USER.pem and VALIDATOR.pem)?

Comment: Yes. I already fixed the problem. It seems that my problem is the http proxy. In knife.rb, I added the http_proxy. Now, I can successfully perform # knife cookbook site list but install and download generated a new ERROR - authorization problems it says. Any ideas? I added the error above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The normal steps for uploading a cookbook from within your chef-repo is:

1. download and extract the cookbook to your `chef-repo/cookbooks` directory
2. upload the cookbook to your chef-server using `knife cookbook upload -a` or `knife cookbook upload [COOKBOOKS...]`
3. run the chef-client on your client node using `chef-client`

This seems to match what you did.

"Installing" a cookbook using `knife cookbook site install COOKBOOK` is essentially the same as downloading it via `knife cookbook site download COOKBOOK` except that the download command saves it as a .tar.gz whereas the install command extracts it and sets up a git submodule so that you can keep it up to date. (See [Managing Cookbooks With Knife - Cookbook Site](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Managing+Cookbooks+With+Knife#ManagingCookbooksWithKnife-CookbookSite).)

You can use tools like [Librarian](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian) or [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) to manage and download cookbooks from any git repo, the Opscode community site, or a local path. Both of these gems work very similarly to Bundler; they generate a `Cheffile.lock` or `Berksfile.lock` which helps you lock cookbooks to a version or commit SHA.

EDIT: I'm not really sure why `knife cookbook site install/download` won't work, though; they don't require any sort of authentication. From the `knife cookbook site` [docs](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Managing+Cookbooks+With+Knife#ManagingCookbooksWithKnife-CookbookSite): "For commands that simply read from the cookbook site (such as download, search, install, and list) you do not need an account on community.opscode.com. For commands that write to the site you need an account on the community site."

It's worth noting that `knife cookbook site download` differs from `knife cookbook download`. The former connects to community.opscode.com, while the latter connects to your chef server. Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you for this. I understand now that running chef-client with a cookbook not from the site is the same as installing it. an finally I managed to connect to tho cookbook site by adding http_proxy to knife.rb. I can perform # knife cookbook site list but not install and download. any ideas? Thank you again!

Comment: No problem! You can try opening a ticket on tickets.opscode.com, they're pretty good about helping out.

I'm running out of space here with the full block of text I want to add, so I'll paste it in my answer above as an edit.

Comment: Hi! I am having trouble with knife cookbook site download from the community.opscode.com. I think the problem is not the authentication to the site but the authorization to the server. I added the error log below for references. Thanks.

Comment: What if I dont want to commit this in git. We are using SVN and we want to skip the whole committing into SVN

Answer (score 0):

Running chef-client is the same as installing the cookbook from the site.

Additionally, I figured out a way to fix this error:

```
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to cookbooks.opscode.com:80 for /api/v1/cookbooks/apache2, retry 1/5
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to cookbooks.opscode.com:80 for /api/v1/cookbooks/apache2, giving up
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

I added http_proxy in /root/.chef/knife.rb

Now, I can successfully perform

```
# knife cookbook site list
```

However, the cookbook site install and download generated a new error.

```
Downloading getting-started from the cookbooks site at version 0.4.0 to /home/chef/getting-started-0.4.0.tar.gz
ERROR: You authenticated successfully to http://10.43.109.236:4000 as my-chefuser but you are not authorized for this action
Response:  #<Net::ReadAdapter:0x2b2afa986ac0>
```

I think the problem now is the permission of Chef server, not the cookbook site because I already have access to it by listing the cookbooks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem too and using this from the Chef ticket system fixed both down- and upload for me: Add these lines to the end of your knife.rb file:

```
http_proxy                "http://proxyserver:8080"
https_proxy               "http://proxyserver:8080"

require 'rest-client'
RestClient.proxy = "http://proxyserver:8080"
```

where obviously you need to replace `proxyserver:8080` needs to be replaced with your specifics.

Comment: My proxy requires authentication. How do I add the credentials in RestClient.proxy ? I have already tried http://username:password@proxyip:port/